# Validar se um CPF já existe na Lista antes de inserir C#

Tags: c#, lista, padrão-dao

Boa noite, estou criando um sistema de vendas (trabalho da faculdade) que conta com um cadastro simples de Clientes (nome e cpf), estamos trabalhando com o Projeto em camadas, estou tendo dificuldade pois estou tentando validar se o CPF já existe na lista utilizando o FOREACH, mas parece não estar funcionando, pois está aceitando todos os CPF'S e na hora que eu peço um return da lista, não está me retornando nada... o que está de errado na validação do Foreach? Agradeço desde já!.

Código em C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using VendasOsorioA.Model;

namespace VendasOsorioA.DAL
{
    class ClienteDAO
    {

        private static List<Cliente> clientes = new List<Cliente>(); 
        public static void CadastrarCliente(Cliente c) 
        {
            foreach (Cliente ClienteCadastrado in clientes)
            {
                if (c.Cpf.Equals(ClienteCadastrado.cpf))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("CPF JÁ EXISTE NA BASE, CADASTRO RECUSADO.");
                }
                else
                {
                    clientes.Add(c);
                    Console.WriteLine("CLIENTE CADASTRADO COM SUCESSO.");
                }
            }    
        }
        public static List<Cliente> RetornarClientes()
        {
            return clientes;
        }
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá! O problema está na lógica que você usou. Seu código está percorrendo a lista de clientes cadastrados, que inicialmente está vazia.
Que tal essa versão?

```
        public static void CadastrarCliente(Cliente c)
        {
            foreach (Cliente ClienteCadastrado in clientes)
            {
                if (c.Cpf.Equals(ClienteCadastrado.Cpf))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("CPF JÁ EXISTE NA BASE, CADASTRO RECUSADO.");
                    return;
                }
            }
            clientes.Add(c);
            Console.WriteLine("CLIENTE CADASTRADO COM SUCESSO.");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu recomendaria alterar seu código fazendo o um `LINQ` ao invés de um `foreach()`. Isto permite-lhe resolver o seu problema e simplifica também a análise do seu código.

Faz assim:

```
private static List<Cliente> clientes = new List<Cliente>(); 

if (clientes.Any(cliente => cliente.cpf == cpf))
{
    clientes.Add(c);
    Console.WriteLine("CLIENTE CADASTRADO COM SUCESSO.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("CPF JÁ EXISTE NA BASE, CADASTRO RECUSADO.");
}
```

Comment: Uma pena não mostrar hora, minuto e segundo das respostas para que ignorâncias como estas não aconteçam. Mas tudo bem, entendo seu ponto de vista.

Comment: Basta manter o pointer/cursor do mouse sobre as indicações de tempo, que tem detalhes exatos de cada ocorrência: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Izxh3.png

Comment: Sinceramente pra mim não importa, apenas importa se ajudou ou não o rapaz ai e se alguem aprendeu algo com isso. -2 de rep por ajudar alguém é um preço barato a se pagar :)

Comment: Então você percebe a troca da palavra SingleOrDefault() por Any() e não percebe a diferença entre a comparação dentro do LINQ? Sem mais...

Comment: Eu retiro a acusação de cópia com pedido de desculpas. Acho que seria mais construtivo o Marconcilio ter dado uma sugestão de melhoria com comentário. Contudo a sua resposta ainda tem informaçoes que não estão corretas. `porque imagina quando sua base possuir milhares de dados, qual seria a performance do foreach()` O `Any` tem a mesma performance que o `foreach` **com dados em memória**

Comment: Desculpas aceitas, é exatamente o que eu pensei, por que ele nao sugeriu uma melhoria. Porém o Any() tem uma particularidade que quando ele encontrar o primeiro registro especificado pela cláusula, ele para a sua execução e já retorna o resultado, não percorrendo todos os dados.

Comment: Victor, esse é exatamente o algoritmo com o `foreach` se for implementado corretamente.

Comment: No final realmente vai dar tudo na mesma, só tomar cuidado com o modo que é implementado. Mas um Any() nao é bem mais bonito de se ver do que um foreach()? rsrs

Answer (score 0):

Uma das formas mais eficientes de fazer isso é usando um `HashSet` e não uma `Lista`.  O `HashSet`é uma implementação duma estrutura de dados que garante que não há dados duplicados em tempo `O(1)`, ao contrário da Lista que tem tempo `O(n)` uma vez que no pior dos casos é necessário percorrer a lista até ao fim para saber se o elemento se encontra nela ou não.

Contudo você precisa de implementar o método `Equals` e `GetHashCode` no tipo que você guarda no seu `HashSet`, neste caso seria no tipo `Cliente`.

```
public class Cliente{
    //... Métodos, campos, propriedades, construtores etc

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        //sua implementação
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        //sua implementação
    }
}

private static HashSet<Cliente> clientes = new HashSet<Cliente>(); 
public static void CadastrarCliente(Cliente c) 
{
    if(clientes.Add(c)){
        Console.WriteLine("CLIENTE CADASTRADO COM SUCESSO.");
    }else{
        Console.WriteLine("CPF JÁ EXISTE NA BASE, CADASTRO RECUSADO.");
    } 
}
```

Outra coisa que está errada no seu código é que você está a mudar a lista dentro do `foreach`, normalmente fazer isso resulta numa excepção.

Comment: Concordo que sua forma é muito eficaz usando HashSet, porém ele aparentemente está iniciando em desenvolvimento, acho que vai bagunçar mais ainda a cabeça dele. Creio que a melhor opção no momento é deixar ele entender o mínimo primeiro.